# Kinect for Windows vs Xbox Kinect

Tags: kinect, openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone know if the Microsoft Kinect for Windows, which slightly different from the Xbox Kinect, is supported by the openni drivers?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57935/kinect-for-windows-vs-xbox-kinect/) by [TFinleyosu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4405/tfinleyosu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 385 on 2013-03-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This have been [discussed before](http://answers.ros.org/question/12876/kinect-for-windows/). Seems still no one have got it working perfectly because OpenNI officially doesn't support it under Linux. Maybe libfreenect could work.

---

Originally posted by [K Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1551/k-chen/) with karma: 391 on 2013-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TFinleyosu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4405/tfinleyosu/) on 2013-03-15**:
Thanks.  I guess I need better search skillz